# Do you have to call R::freeze() in every script when using Redbean PHP ORM?

Tags: php, orm, redbean

Calling R::freeze() does not store any new data in the database (to my knowledge), how would a php script executed at a later date be aware that I called freeze() when I built the database? Should I be using freeze at the start of every one of my php scripts which use redbean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be in the start of the script on every page that uses Redbean.  I just reviewed the code, and there is no changes made anywhere that change it permanently.  That being said, you have two options, at the start of every page, call `R::freeze()` -OR- edit `rb.php` around line 1380 and change `private $isFrozen=false;` to `private $isFrozen=true;`.